# Highchart JS set min Y Axis from 0 to 1

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I tried setting the min of the Y Axis to 1 as seen in my js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e2XPx/

Anyone know how to make the 0 value be 1 by default?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container0').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Keyword: test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:['04-14-2013','04-15-2013','04-16-2013','04-17-2013','04-18-2013','04-19-2013','04-20-2013']
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 1,


            title: {
                text: 'Number'

            },
            reversed: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'test',
            data:   [1,4,5,2,6,7,8]
        }],
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPostitions: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions or tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner